# $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}\sin(x)}{(e^{x}-1)\log(1+x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the integral check if it converges:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}\sin(x)}{(e^{x}-1)\log(1+x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is convergent. Hints for proof: As $ x \to 0$, $ \frac {\sin x} {\mathrm{e}^{x}-1} \to 1$; also $\log(1+x) \sim x$ so the integrand behaves like a constant times $\frac 1 {\sqrt x}$ which gives convergence of the integral near $0$. Near $\infty$ the presence of $\mathrm{e}^{x}$ in the denominator makes it easy to prove convergence.